# Is it possible to create Warp Signs that can only be used every hour in Minecraft Essentials?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

I am trying to create a "dungeon," in Minecraft, but I do not want players to be able to continuously do it. I want there to be a gap of one hour before they can use the sign again. By this, I mean a Warp sign.

The idea is that the player presses the warp sign, but cannot press it again for another hour (Or any amount of time).

I have seen this before on others servers and would like to know what plugin it is. Is these essentials' warp signs?

If they are, (or not) how do I create what I am talkin about?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use the [CommandSigns](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/command-signs/) plugin to achieve this.

**This assumes that the dungeon can be reached with `/warp Dungeon` and standard players have no access to it via the commands; only signs.**

Firstly, the `~` identifier allows you to place a limit on the sign, and the `^` identifier executes the command under the player's name, but with the `'*'` permission node.
*Note that this does not give them full command permissions, only just for the sign's execution; command stated in the sign.*

You can visit the [BukkitDev Wiki page](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/command-signs/pages/reference-guide/special-characters/#w-conditions-restrictions-v1-7-9) for more information.

---

#### Here's how you set it up.

1. Place a sign, you can color it, make it fancy - Do whatever you want.
   *Just ensure it doesn't follow Essential's sign formatting.*
2. Enter the following command in the chat: `/cmds add ~3600`
   *This defines a sign, with a execution cooldown of 3,600 seconds (or 60 minutes).

   Except, your sign does nothing.*
3. Right click (or punch) your sign that you want this to be applied to.
4. Enter the following command: `/cmds edit` and punch the sign that you created in Step 2.
5. Enter the following command: `/cmds insert 2 /^warp Dungeon`.
6. Punch/right-click the sign.
7. You're done.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the plugin BoosCooldowns on the Spigot website. http://www.spigotmc.org/resources/booscooldowns.2759/

You would want to create a cooldown timer for the  signs.use.warp   command.

This is a plugin you have to purchase to get the latest version but it is continually updated. I have seen older free versions on some webites but I think it only cost $3 and it is worth it. I use it for numerous commands and it is easy to configure per player or group.

Comment: And yes this would be for the Essentials warp signs or any Essentials commands, The full command for the sign being essentials.signs.use.warp

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in vanilla by using a scoreboard objective. Create the objective using: `/scoreboard objectives add time dummy time` and make the sign that teleports you out set `@p`'s score for `time` to 0: `/scoreboard players set @p time 0` and have whatever teleports you to the dungeon test to see if the score is the minimum required (60, when using a one-minute clock) by using this command: `/testfor @p[score_time_min_60]`. Make a hopper coming **out** of that command block into the one that teleports you to the dungeon. To increase the score each time you exit the dungeon, use a one-minute clock with a command block at the end with the command: `/scoreboard players add @a[score_time_min_0] time 1`